# User deleted helpful answers because of "Down for non-existent maintenance"?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, vote-to-undelete

I have this kind of *canonical Q&A* [Why does reading a struct record fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi) under my aegis.

Well, a user posted two IMHO useful answers there, but deleted them leaving a reason in the deleted questions:

[image]

Should I respect the user's will to delete their (even upvoted answers), or should I vote to undelete (I'm tempted at least vote to undelete the upvoted answer, and rollback after reopening)?

I'm not so sure what they've meant with *"**Down for non-existent maintenance.**"*, is it I should improve the question (can't see hints from the original answers)?

Comment: I guess you should have flagged for a mod to look into it and then gone your merry way.

Comment: Well, how should a mod flag really help here? It's about judging the (original) content, or is it about judging the behavior?

Comment: Pretty funny.  He just withdrew the posts, probably found a logical mistake in them.  Don't undelete mistakes.

Comment: @HansPassant _"probably found a logical mistake in them"_ Could well be, I've been overlooking such, being too enthusiastic for getting more contributions :-P ...

Comment: 1. Take a look to make sure it's really valuable content (which includes not being redundant). 2. Notify the mods that you saw him delete x valuable posts (links to the others), and they should look whether it's a pattern and something concerning.

Comment: What still confuses me, is that ***Down for non-existent maintenance.*** message, did they mean maintenance of their own efforts, or the question itself?

Comment: I think it's just a joke (at least, not meant to be taken very seriously). Referencing the common "down for maintenance"-type messages on websites, but saying the answer isn't really under maintenance and isn't coming back.

Comment: Why would not you mail that person directly?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've left comments. Well, the user offers an eMail address at their profile, but usually I'm reluctant mailing other SO users directly for clarifications.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Why would you?

Comment: Simply flag it if you feel the need and move on.

Comment: @PeeHaa Why would you? Because there's nothing preventing you and if they provided their email, then it's safe to say they won't be too bothered by receiving an email. If they didn't want to be emailed, they can remove it from their profile.

Comment: You sound like a proper spammer :P

Comment: So, did you look at the original content?  Was it actually a misread of your question (ie, did it answer the wrong question) as the edit history implies?  If so, deleting it is *good* in that it removes noise.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I removed the posts because they **don't actually work**. Normally I keep posts alive if they answer the question and are atleast helpful, and those were neither. I'll go ahead and post a working version in a few minutes. The "down for non-existent maintenance" line was cool joke I thought up at the last minute before deleting them (pretty funny, huh?) :P

Also, I'm happy to take an email from anyone! :)

Comment: madness, removing posts because they're wrong, where will it all end :)

Comment: Generally the Internet prefers you not destroy information, even if it's wrong. Better to strike it all out and explain why. :)

Comment: I'm just glad you explained the joke because I was sure I was missing something, like a reference or a meme.

Comment: @wmassingham Though the SE system at least implicitly encourages you to remove it. I'm not sure how enlightened most voters would be if you start your answer with, "**EDIT:** I'm wrong", even if it's immediately followed by, "... and here's why". Though don't worry, just like your dark profile in Facebook, the right people can still see your deleted info. Nobody expects the Internet Retention. ;^)

Comment: It would certainly have been helpful to include an explanation for your deletes; as @πάνταῥεῖ I would have appreciated that a lot more than your joke, though you could have left that in too, I suppose.

Comment: "Better to strike it all out and explain why. :)" @BSMP, not really. I once made an answer, and hit the "add answer" button too soon by mistake. As I quite often do, I often give different answers, and some general context at start, that has value only once the answer correctly written. Even though I edited to add a line "answer in progress", I could see my answer being downvoted in almost real time, as I was still editing it. Now when such a thing happens, I prefer to delete my answer, make the edit in my favorite editor, and reopen it as I'm posting the changes.

Comment: @wmassingham although the Internet will save it without your consent anyway in some dark corner of cyberspace. So not quite ever destroyed once it is in cyberspace...

Comment: for a future, consider leaving for 10k readers deletion explanation that is [easier to understand](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt8TC.png "example")

Comment: @zmo - I think you meant to direct that comment to wmassingham.

Comment: @BSMP err… right, got distracted :-)

Answer (score -5):

Still having trouble deleting answers from the Android app; will clean up later.

Comment: No, my question was exactly about that phrase I mentioned in the title. The answer was modified meanwhile (that's why I've put a screenshot in my question).

Comment: @keshlam, should your answer be deleted since this is not an answer? It would be better posted as a comment.

Comment: Disagree but not worth arguing.